# How to test user permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2017

I have two server users, lets say *admin* and *notadmin*. I need to test *notadmin*'s permissions. I need set and test VIEW SERVER STATE permission on *notadmin*, but usually I have access only to database only as *admin*. My *admin* is not sysadmin, because of problem with default schema (sysadmins have always default schema dbo, but i need something else), but I can set almost any permissions I need.

I proceed from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-perms-by-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For testing permissions there is `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` and it works well. So I tried to impersonate *notadmin*. I set `IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN` permission to *admin*, and it works well. I test it this way (on master db):

```
SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('notadmin', 'LOGIN', 'IMPERSONATE')  -- return 1
EXECUTE AS login = 'notadmin'
    SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'VIEW SERVER STATE')  -- return 1
REVERT
```

Because I don't like ANY (this way I can impersonate someone with sysadmin role), I tried set this

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::admin to notadmin
```

and then a run same query. But it failed - returned 0 and error:
*Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "notadmin" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.*

Principal have to exist and can by impersonated, with IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN it works. So which permission I need to impersonate *notadmin*?

Or is there some other way how can I test some other db user permission and do not allow impersonate any other users?

---

**Edit (16.04.2021 12:13):**
I find that `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME` returns same values as system views in master db. So `SELECT * FROM sys.server_permissions` is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GRANT IMPERSONATE ON LOGIN::admin to notadmin` is telling SQL Server that you want to give the `IMPERSONATE` permission to the `notadmin` account so that it can `IMPERSONATE` other users. It sounds like your goal is the opposite, that you want to impersonate the `notadmin` account from the `admin` account. You already are accomplishing this when you run the SQL code `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'notadmin'` (when you're logged in as your `admin` account).

Comment: Thanks for help,.. I am complete idiot. There was necessary only second pair of eyes.

Comment: @VítBednář lol no problem! You're definitely not an idiot, the security stuff in SQL Server *can* be a little confusing at first, and a second set of eyes can always help any problem.  Best of luck!